# Is this matrix equal to the identity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra

In the context of this larger problem, I have a question about the meaning of the matrix $W$ here.

The time reversal operator $\Theta$ can be written $$\Theta = UK$$ and also as $$\Theta = U'K'$$ where $K|n\rangle = |n\rangle$ and  $K'|\nu\rangle = |\nu\rangle$. $\{|n\rangle\}$ and$ \{|\nu\rangle\}$ are orthonormal basis here. The actual problem is to show that $U'=WUW^T $ where $W$ is a unitary operator whose matrix elements are given by $W_{\nu,n}=\langle\nu |n\rangle$. Now, here is my question. The $W$ operator can be written as
$$\sum_{\nu,n} |\nu\rangle W_{\nu,n}\langle n| =\sum_{\nu,n} |\nu\rangle \langle\nu |n\rangle\langle n|\tag{$1$}$$
which is just two completeness relations and so it is the identity. This makes sense to me because if we are regarding $W$ as a change of basis matrix, then the actual state vectors should not be changed by them (because changing the basis yields the same vector). I think this is a passive transformation, not totally sure. However, on the other hand, if $W$ is the identity, then how does $U' = WUW^T$ make sense here, given that $U'$ is decidedly not the same as $U$. How is the meaning of $W$ changing from one expression to the next.
[Related.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/576531/) I also read [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/294015/) but I am struggling to understand how $W$ can be simultaneously written as the identity but then not be the identity.

Comment: @Albert What do you mean? If $W_{\nu n}:= \langle \nu|n\rangle$, then eq. $(1)$ is correct. It simply reads $W= I W I = \sum\limits_{v,n} \langle \nu|W|n\rangle\, |\nu\rangle\langle n|  = I$ if $W_{\nu,n}$ is supposed to mean $\langle \nu|W|n\rangle$. So either the definition of $W_{\nu,n}$ is different or it is a typo in the exercise text or so. Also the transpose instead of adjoint looks weird.

Comment: @TobiasFünke, I agree, excuse me for the confusion.

Comment: If $|n\rangle$ is a basis, and $K$ is a linear operator obeying $K|n\rangle = |n\rangle$ then $K$ is the identity. Proof: $$K|\phi\rangle = K\sum_n c_n |n\rangle = \sum_n c_n K|n\rangle = \sum_n c_n |n\rangle = |\phi\rangle,$$ with the same argument for $K'$. That said, why bother introducing these $K$ and $K'$?

Comment: $K$ is anti-linear, @Gold

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense, thanks!